# Test convergence, find $\alpha$ which makes integral converge

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm testing the convergence of this improper integral

$$\int_2^{\infty} x(\ln x)^{\alpha} dx$$

I used the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{x}$ which is divergent, I found that this integral diverges for all values of $\alpha$.

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

Observe that the integrand is positive and we have, for all real values of $\alpha$,
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(x(\ln x)^{\alpha}\right)=+\infty 
$$ thus the initial integral is **divergent**.